# Vaadin Grid Util: how to create different tables using dynamic container?

Tags: grid, containers, vaadin

I have different kind of tables in my database (~100), and I want user on click show these tables in grid. How to use one container to be able to represent different tables? 
In the code below I used grid.addColumn(), grid.addRow()

```
 public Grid genGrid(TableGrid tg) {

    final Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.setSizeFull();


         for(ColumnDefinition c:tg.getColumns()){

             if(c.getColumnType().equals("String")){
                grid.addColumn(c.getColumnName(), String.class);}
             if(c.getColumnType().equals("int")){
                grid.addColumn(c.getColumnName(), Integer.class);}
             if(c.getColumnType().equals("date")){
                grid.addColumn(c.getColumnName(), Date.class);}
             if(c.getColumnType().equals("boolean")){
                grid.addColumn(c.getColumnName(), Boolean.class);
             }
             if(c.getColumnType().equals("dictionary")){
                 grid.addColumn(c.getColumnName(), String.class);  
             }
             if(c.getColumnType().equals("dictionary2")){
                 grid.addColumn(c.getColumnName(), Enum.class);
             }

    }


        for(Row r:tg.getRows()){    
             Object[] a = new Object[r.getCells().size()];
             for(int i =0; i<a.length; i++){
             if (!grid.getColumns().get(i).equals("dictionary2")){
                     System.out.println(r.getCells().get(i).getCellValue().toString());
                     a[i] = r.getCells().get(i).getCellValue();  
                 } else {
                 a[i] = Enum.valueOf(, name)
                }

            }
        grid.addRow(a);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What container type do you use as data source?

Comment: @AndréSchild, hello. Im not using any container. Just adding columns one by one (because i dont know exact number of columns and its types is coming from db), and then adding rows as the object. I have classes: 'ColumnDefinition {coulmnName, type} Table{ List<ColumnDefinition> columns, List<Row> rows} Row {List<Cell> cells} Cell{ Object cellValue }'

Comment: so what is your question? When you use a vaadin container, you can specify it to use a new dbtable and the vaadin table adjusts automagically